# Encrypting only the value in key-value pair in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, encryption

guys I want to implement the encryption . And that to only to value in key-value pair in mongodb.Can anyone please provide a workable solution

Answer (score 0):

As MongoDB 3.2 enables encrypted storage engine, you don't need any third party APIs to encrypts your data before insertion.
The following link may be helpful: [MongoDB encryption](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-encryption-at-rest/)

Comment: Yeah ,but that doesn't provide the the field level encryption explicitly.